# Leaflet layer visualization problems with ajax Error: parseResponse was not called

Tags: ajax, leaflet, geoserver, leaflet.markercluster

I'm creating a Leaflet viewer where I use ajax to get a geoserver OWS to be able to customize the display style with the following function:

```
function GetGeoserverJson(layer,geoserverURL,geoserverLayerName,layerAtributes,layerStyle) {

defaultParameters = {
service: 'WFS',
version: '1.0.0',
request: 'GetFeature',
maxFeatures: 120000,
outputFormat: 'text/javascript'
};
parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters,geoserverLayerName);
console.log(parameters)
$.ajax({
url: geoserverURL + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse',
    success: function (data) {
geoJsonLayer= new L.GeoJSON(data,{pointToLayer: function (geoJsonPoint, latlng) {return 
L.circleMarker(latlng);}, onEachFeature: layerAtributes, style:layerStyle})
layerName.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
    }
});
}
```

Layers code:

```
geoserverURL= 'http://urladdress/geoserver/workspace/ows'

function PresenceAttributes(feature, layer) {
  // layer.bindPopup("<b>Zone:</b> <br>"+feature.properties.zone+"<br><b>Taxon:</b><br>"+feature.properties.taxon+"<br><b>Species:</b> <br><i>"+feature.properties.species+"</i>");
    layer.bindPopup(
        "<table class='featureInfo'><caption class='featureInfo'>Presence</caption><tbody><tr><th>source</th><th>latitude</th><th>longitude</th></tr><tr><td>"
        +feature.properties.source+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.latitude+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.longitude+"</td></tr></tbody></table>"
    );
}


var NISStyle= function(feature) {
            // console.log(feature)
            var taxon_nis=feature.properties.taxon_class;
            switch (taxon_nis) {
                case "Bivalvia":    {return {color:"#d19211"};}
                case "Gastropoda": {return {color:"#8a6fce"};}
                case "Polyplacophora": {return {color:"#2fbb00"};}
                }
        }

var  NISAttributes= function(feature, layer) {
  // layer.bindPopup("<b>Zone:</b> <br>"+feature.properties.zone+"<br><b>Taxon:</b><br>"+feature.properties.taxon+"<br><b>Species:</b> <br><i>"+feature.properties.species+"</i>");
    layer.bindPopup(
        "<table class='featureInfo'><caption class='featureInfo'>NIS historical</caption><tbody><tr><th>latitude</th><th>longitude</th><th>country</th></th><th>Site Name</th></th><th>Class</th><th>Species</th><th>Year first record</th><th>Reference</th></tr><tr><td>"
        +feature.properties.latitude+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.longitude+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.country+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.site_name+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.taxon_class+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.species+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.year_first+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.reference+"</td></tr></tbody></table>"
    );
}

var ParasitesAttributes= function (feature, layer) {

  // layer.bindPopup("<b>Zone:</b> <br>"+feature.properties.zone+"<br><b>Taxon:</b><br>"+feature.properties.taxon+"<br><b>Species:</b> <br><i>"+feature.properties.species+"</i>");
    layer.bindPopup(
        "<table class='featureInfo'><caption class='featureInfo'>Parasites</caption><tbody><tr><th>Country</th><th>Zone</th><th>Latitude</th><th>Longitude</th><th>Taxon</th><th>Species</th></tr><tr><td>"
        +feature.properties.country+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.zone+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.latitude+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.longitude+"</td><td>"+feature.properties.taxon
        +"</td><td>"+feature.properties.species+"</td></tr></tbody></table>"
    );
}

var ParasytesStyle= function (feature){
                var taxon_parasites=feature.properties.taxon_id;
                switch (taxon_parasites) {
                    case 1: {return {color:"#4c6fb6"};} // Artropoda-
                    case 2: {return {color:"#fcbf7d"};} //Alveolata-
                    case 3: {return {color:"#3cbfbf"};} //Platelminthes-
                    case 4: {return {color:"#b9d989"};} //Rhizaria-
                    case 5: {return {color:"#ff7f00"};} //Amoebozoa
                    case 6: {return {color:"#de524b"};} //Bacteria-
                    case 7: {return {color:"#aebaca"};} // Others-
                    case 8: {return {color:"#f47a6a"};} //Fungi-
                    case 9: {return {color:"#999999"};} //ND-
                    // case 10: {return {color:"grey"}};
                    // case 11: {return {color:"white"}};

                }
    }

var GeoservePresence={typeName:'COCKLES:aa_cockles_presence'};
var GeoserveNIS={typeName:'COCKLES:aa_nis_historical'};
var GeoserveParasites={typeName:'COCKLES:aa_cockles_pathogens'}

var CocklesPresence= new L.markerClusterGroup();
var CocklesNISAA= new L.markerClusterGroup();
var CocklesParasites= new L.markerClusterGroup(); 


GetGeoserverJson(CocklesPresence,CetmarGeoserver,GeoservePresence,PresenceAttributes,{color:"#FFC000"});
        GetGeoserverJson(CocklesNISAA,CetmarGeoserver,GeoserveNIS,NISAttributes,NISStyle);
        GetGeoserverJson(CocklesParasites,CetmarGeoserver,GeoserveParasites,ParasitesAttributes,ParasytesStyle);
```

When I code only one layer it works perfectly, but if I run the function with more layers, layers represent data incorrectly (data of NIS layer are represented in parasites one, etc.) I don't really know much about ajax and I'm new to javascript and Leaflet, so I hardly can figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe some problem with asynchronism? Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do mean by "_it doesn't work properly_"? What error message do you get? Make sure to provide enough details and code for people to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: The error is the following: "Uncaught ReferenceError: parseResponse is not defined"  I try to load 2 layers, one called layera and other called layerb. The error is supposed to occur in layerb. However, while the layera does not load, the layerb loads with the layout data but with the layerb style.

Comment: You very probably do not need the `dataType: 'jsonp'` (but json instead), which uses your `jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse'` option, which expects a "parseResponse" function to be defined in your script, but seems to be missing. But since you specify a success callback anyway, you do not need JSONP.

Comment: I still have the same problem and I'm not able to solve it. I suspect that some asyncronous exectution is mixing the diferent layers I'm creating with this function, but after struggling for a solution, I couldt figure it out. I include the rest of code I'm using for each  Leaflet layer: